# parsing an expression using DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

I try to parse a list of identifiers with DCG but I fail to do it,

**example**

```
                          ::=
                            |
                          __|____
                         |       |
                        Id     Id,'(',Ids,')'.
                                       _|_
                                      |   |
                                     Id   Id,
```

-

```
ids ::= id.
ids ::= id(id1,id2,...).
```

**example of identifier to verify**

```
  exp1 = 'id_0'
  exp3 = 'id_1(i)'
  exp2 = 'id_2(i1,i2)'
```

**code** edit

```
id([Id]) --> [Id].
id([Id|Ids]) --> [Id,'('], ids(Ids), [')'].

ids([Id]) --> [Id].
ids([Id|Ids]) --> [Id], ids(Ids).
```

someone tell me where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first see what you are actually **currently** describing with (for example) `id//1`, using the **most general** query:

```
?- phrase(id(Is), Ls).
Is = Ls, Ls = [_G884] ;
Is = [_G884|_G885],
Ls = [_G884, '(', ids(_G885), ')'].
```

Trying out the most general query is often a good way to find out more about a relation. In this case, we already note two very important things:

1. Regarding the list `Ls` of tokens, the first solution is clearly **more general** than intended. No clause that you add to this program (while preserving [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)) can remove this flaw. Therefore, you need to make the first rule **more specific**.
2. The tokens described by the second answer do not actually match the grammar, because they contain the concrete token `ids(_)`. This points you to the fact that you are intermingling DCG rule names with the tokens you want to describe.

For a start, let us first focus an describing the list of **tokens** that we want to describe. This simplifies the code somewhat, since we do not have to deal with so many things at once.

I suggest you start with the following:

```
ids --> [id].
ids --> [id,'('], ids_, [')'].

ids_ --> ids, more_ids_.

more_ids_ --> [].
more_ids_ --> [,], ids_.
```

Notice the helpful pattern that allows us to specify "more of the same", which is either *nothing* or a *comma* **and then** "the same".

I suppose you will eventually make this more general, and for example accept also other identifiers besides the concrete token `id`. The place to do this is clear from the code above, and I leave it as an easy exercise.

Notice that we can already use this to see whether we are describing **only** intended lists of tokens:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(ids, Ls).
Ls = [id] ;
Ls = [id, '(', id, ')'] ;
Ls = [id, '(', id, ',', id, ')'] ;
Ls = [id, '(', id, '(', id, ')', ')'] ;
etc.
```

I am using `length/2` for fair enumeration.

Once you have made sure that you are describing all and only lists of tokens you intended, you can then start to relate such lists of tokens to other Prolog terms. This will often involve `(=..)/2` and other relations between terms.

Comment: thnx but it's not like `id(id(id))`, it's like `id(id1,id2,id3,...)` and **id** is variable ,

Comment: Already in your initial question, you need to precisely specify what you actually want to describe. What is `id1`, `id2` etc.? What is "variable"? A list of letters? Of digits? Of bytes? etc. Still, no matter what you actually mean to describe by `id` (in my answer, I chose literally `id`), you can easily achieve it with a few modifications to the snippet I posted. Start with `id//0`: What do you want it to describe? `id --> ...`. Then take it from there. The `more_ids_//0` nonterminal shows you how to describe cases of "more of the same, separated by comma".

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing that a DCG, when translated to Prolog, handles symbols enclosed between squares as **terminals**.

So, your clauses like

```
id([Id|Ids]) --> [Id,'(',ids(Ids),')'].
```

are deemed to fail, except when a specific pattern of **terminals** is given. Let's try, in SWI-Prolog:

```
1 ?- [user].
id([Id|Ids]) --> [Id,'(',ids(Ids),')'].
|: 
true.

2 ?- phrase(id(L), [me,'(',ids([1,2,3]),')']).
L = [me, 1, 2, 3].
```

you can see that ids/1 is not handled as a **non**-terminal.

Comment: thnx, the list of identifiers are extracted from a file
like
`List = [ 'id (i1, i2, i3)', 'Var', 'var1, var2' | ...].`, how to eliminate the braces `'`_`'` of the first element ?

Comment: not sure I understand the question ... maybe `?- With='\'abc\'', atom_codes(With,CWs),append([[0''],Cs,[0'']],CWs),atom_codes(Out,Cs).`

Comment: it's works in PDT-SWI but not with SPIDER-SICStus :(

Comment: could be that append/2 isn't available. Another, portable, way: `With='\'abc\'', sub_atom(With,1,_,0,T),sub_atom(T,0,_,1,Out).`